# undefined offset when using php explode()

Tags: php, explode

I've written what I thought was a very simple use of the php `explode()` function to split a name into forename and surname:

```
// split name into first and last
$split = explode(' ', $fullname, 2);
$first = $split[0];
$last = $split[1];
```

However, this is throwing up a php error with the message `"Undefined offset: 1"`. The function still seems to work, but I'd like to clear up whatever is causing the error. I've checked the [php manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) but their examples use the same syntax as above.
I think I understand what an undefined offset is, but I can't see why my code is generating the error!

Comment: Can you provide the value of `$fullname` that gives you the error?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

this is because your fullname doesn't contain a space. You can use a simple trick to make sure the space is always where

```
 $split = explode(' ', "$fullname ");
```

(note the space inside the quotes)

BTW, you can use list() function to simplify your code

```
  list($first, $last) = explode(' ', "$fullname ");
```

Comment: That's not true, if explode doesn't find the string you are using it'll return an array with a single position and the full text in that position.

Comment: you need as many split chars as var to assign: e.g. `list($size, $ctype, $sample, $desc) = explode(',', $item.',,,,');` so it's assured you always get an assignment

Comment: Be careful with this hack, as with third parameter in `explode` it can be tricky ie: `$string = 'abc abc'; list($first, $last) = explode(' ', "$string ", 2);`. The result of $last is: "abc " with space at the end!

Comment: This is a great trick. To simplify your code even further, you don't need list() at all: [$first, $last] = explode(' ', "$fullname ");

Comment: Works for PayPal IPN listener code `explode("=", "$lines[$i]=");` - adding the `=` prevents the error where there is no `=` in the returned post string.

Answer (score 22):

**Use `array_pad`**

e.q.:
`$split = array_pad(explode(' ', $fullname), 2, null);`

- `explode` will split your string into an array without any limits.
- `array_pad` will fill the exploded array with `null` values if it has less than `2` entries.

---

See [array_pad](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)

Answer (score 5):

This could be due the fact that `$fullname` did not contain a space character.

This example should fix your problem w/o displaying this notice:

```
$split = explode(' ', $fullname, 2);
$first = @$split[0];
$last = @$split[1];
```

Now if `$fullname` is `"musoNic80"` you won't get a notice message.

Note the use of `"@"` characters.

HTH
Elias

Comment: Makes sense, but I'd rather find a way of fixing the problem rather than supressing the errors. Thanks though for explaining the cause!

Answer (score 4):

BTW, that algorithm won't work all the time. Think about two-word Latina or Italian surnames names like "De Castro", "Dela Cruz", "La Rosa", etc. Split will return 3 instead of 2 words:

```
Array {
  [0] => 'Pedro'
  [1] => 'De'
  [1] => 'Castro'
}
```

You'll end up with messages like "Welcome back Ana De" or "Editing Profile of Monsour La".

Same thing will happen for two-word names like "Anne Marie Miller", "William Howard Taft", etc.

Just a tip.

Comment: Changing the third flag in `explode(' ', $fullname, 2)` to `explode(' ', $fullname, 1)` solves this.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, whatever `$fullname` is doesn't contain a space, so `$split` is an array containing a single element, so `$split[1]` refers to an undefined offset.

Answer (score 2):

`array_pad` is the only valid answer in this thread, all others are ugly hacks that can explode into your face. With `array_pad` you can always be sure that the amount of elements is correct and filled.
Especially important when using with a `list()` type output.

Answer (score 1):

That' strange, it's working correct here. When i try with a string `the cat walks` and also just `the` will do and not produce an error. I've outputted it with `print_r`

What's your `$fullname` looks like when you get the error?