# Php explode string only if the string contains '.'

Tags: php

I have this explode (with list):

```
$dm = "blablabla.ff";
list($d, $l) = explode('.', $dm, 2);
```

Now, i want the explode will cut the string only if the string contains `.`
because the list will return error if the string not contains `.`, error like this: `Undefined offset: 1`.

How can i do this short way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Comment: @Federico No, in addition i search solution for the `Undefined offset: 1` problem.

Comment: this is not a good approach if your wanting a filename extension (which it kind of looks like)

Comment: @Dagon actually i want a domain tld(extension)

Comment: if you had only asked that in the first  place ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting domain extension from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487559/getting-domain-extension-from-url)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6576365/3392762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dm = "blablabla.ff";
if(strpos($dm,".") !== false){
    list($d, $l) = explode('.', $dm, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explode `$dm = "blablabla.ff";` you get two arrays. 
one for $d and one for $l.

```
$d = 'blablabla';
$l = 'ff';
```

If you explode `$dm = "blablablaff";` you get one array. 
One for $d and no one for $l.

```
$d = 'blablablaff';
$l = null;
```

Now if you have no arrays to fill the list ($l) it will error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    <?php
        $dm     = "blablabla.ff";
        $d      = null;
        $l      = null;

        if( stristr($dm, ".")){
            list($d, $l) = explode('.', $dm, 2);
        }       

        var_dump($d, $l);
```