# PHP: undefined offset in explode()

Tags: php, offset

I have this:

```
list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(' ', $queryString);
```

Sometiems $lastname does not gets defined, and it's there i am getting undefined offset error.

Because it can not find anything to put in $lastname, i guess.

After the explode() i have:

```
if(!$lastname) { $lastname = $firstname; }
```

So my question is how can i define it as the $firstname if $lastname is not defined (if you wrote only 'Adam' and not 'Adam Thompson', the lastname should be defined so it is 'Adam Adam')

It does this for me now, but I am receiving the offset error

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_pad(explode(' ', $queryString, 2), 2, null);
```

The `2` in `explode()` ensures, that there are *at most* 2 values and `array_pad()` ensures, that there are *at least* 2 values. If there is no space character , `$lastname` is `null`. This you can use to decide what comes next

```
$lastname = is_null($lastname) ? $firstname : $lastname;
```

Little update: For this specific case you can use a little trick

```
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_pad(explode(' ', $queryString, 2), 2, $queryString);
```

This will do all that in one step. It should work, because

- There is always at least one value (for `$firstname`)
- If there is one value, then `$queryString == $firstname`. Thats now the value that is used to fill the array up to 2 values (which is exactly one, because one value we already have)
- If there are two values, then the array is not filled with `$queryString`, because we already have 2 values

At least for readability I would prefer the first more obvious solution.

Comment: +1 Interesting solution. Although I'd argue it's overkill for such a simple thing.

Comment: I can't follow... The first solution just adds one single function call. That's a single function call, not "overkill". Additional `array_pad()` is the function, that does (and is designed for) exactly this use case: Ensuring, that there are at least `x` elements. By saying "its overkill" you also say, that `array_pad()` is completely useless.

Comment: Slow down there **King**. That's a bit of a stretch - *overkill = `array_pad()` is useless*. I said no such thing. As I pointed out, it's an interesting solution. But, I maintain 3 function calls when 1 would do is *overkill*. Furthermore, I think storing first name, in a variable called `$lastname` is unintuitive and leads to poor code. I'd rather encourage the OP to do it *better*, than make it work.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I have _two_ function calls (remind, that `list()` is a language construct), which besides are both native C functions, and you have one function call, but an additional `if`-construct. If you can reliable _measure_ a _significant_ difference, than I may agree, that it is overkill.

Comment: Could someone possibly tell me, why I have 2 servers - one with PHP 5.2.6, and the second with 5.3.3, - and I get the error `Undefined offset` only in 5.3.3, while the same code on the same data works smoothly in 5.2.6?

Comment: @Stan Probably because of `error_reporting`-settings, but to be honest: I am not sure, if this is related to this question/answer :?

Answer (score 4):

Try appending a space:

```
list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(' ', $queryString . ' ' );
```

shouldn't have to change a thing after that.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting an *Error*, but a *Notice*.

Although this is *acceptable* since PHP is a dynamic language, you can prevent it with [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
if(!isset($lastname)) {
  $lastname = $firstname;
}
```

#### UPDATE

Per the comments, `list()` is the culprit for the *Notice*. In which case, I wouldn't recommend the use of `list()` when `explode()` doesn't yield the appropriate number of parameters.

If you must, the answer by **brady** or [undefined offset when using php explode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807849/undefined-offset-when-using-php-explode) *can* work. Although it's pretty *ugly* in my opinion. I believe your code would be much more intuitive if you just did the following:

```
$name = explode(' ', $queryString);

if (isset($name[1])) {
  // show lastname
}
else {
  // show firstname
}
```

Comment: the notice comes at the explode() so even if i wrap the if in isset() it appears still

Comment: @Jason McCreary `isset` does not prevent the Notice, as it is thrown in the `list` assignment

Comment: @brian_d, you're right. I wouldn't encourage the use of `list()` in this case then.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this today. my solution was not the above,
(which had no effect) mine was the following:

```
while (!feof($fh))
{
    $line = fgets($fh);
    print $line;
}
```

instead of doing:

```
while ($line = fgets($fh))
{
     print $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear why this works, but the notice will go away.  First, with this code I get the undefined offset notice:

```
list($month, $day, $year)=explode('-', $dateToChange, 3);
```

However, with this code, I don't:

```
list($month, $day, $year, $junk)=explode('-', $dateToChange.'---', 4);
```

Also note, with '-' or '--' appended to $dateToChange, I will get the offset notice.  It takes three dashes for it to go away in my example with four variables.  $junk contains the two dashes (one being a separator).

Comment: Best not to simply provide hacks - SO is best with reasoning behind answers.