# Php code shows offset error

Tags: php, oop, templates, file-io, runtime-error

I am a beginner of smarty php templating system and I'm going through a book `Smarty PHP Template Programming`. The very first example on chapter 2 is as follows.

In the root folder, we have a file named `data.txt` with the following information.

```
Title=> Building Websites with VB.NET and DotNetNuke 3.0 
Image=> 1904811272.jpg 
Author=> Daniel N. Egan 
Description=> A practical guide to creating and maintaining your own website with DotNetNuke, the free, open source evolution of Microsoft's IBuySpy Portal 
Year=> 2005 
Price=> 39.99 

Title=> SSL VPN : Understanding, evaluating and planning secure, web-based remote access 
Image=> 1904811078.jpg 
Author=> Joseph Steinberg, Tim Speed, Simon Jenner 
Description=> A comprehensive overview of SSL VPN technologies and design strategies 
Year=> 2005 
Price=> 49.99 

Title=> Windows Server 2003 Active Directory Design and Implementation=> Creating, Migrating, and Merging Networks 
Image=> 1904811086.jpg 
Author=> John Savill 
Description=> A unique, scenario-based approach to selecting and implementing the best Active Directory design for your environment 
Year=> 2005 
Price=> 59.99
```

Next step is to retrieve the data from `data.txt`. For this, a file named `get_data.php` in the root folder with the following content:

```
<?php

    class books {

        public $title = array(); 
        public $image = array(); 
        public $author = array(); 
        public $description = array(); 
        public $year = array();
        public $price = array(); 

        private $filename = "data.txt";

        //class constructor
        function __construct()
            {
                //get the lines as an array
                $i=-1;
                $lines = file($this->filename);
                // strip "\n" at the end of each array
                // get each variable in an array

                foreach ( $lines as $line) {
                if (strlen($line) > 2) {

                    $line = rtrim($line);

                    list($what, $content) = explode("=>", $line);

                    if ($what == "Title") {
                        $i++;
                        $this->title[$i]=$content;
                        }
                    elseif ($what == "Image") {
                        $this->image[$i]=$content;
                        }
                    elseif ($what == "Author") {
                        $this->author[$i]=$content;
                        }
                    elseif ($what == "Description") {
                        $this->description[$i]=$content;
                        }
                    elseif ($what == "Year") {
                        $this->year[$i]=$content;
                        }
                    elseif ($what == "Price") {
                        $this->price[$i]=$content;

                        };
                        };
                    };

                } // end constructor

                } // end GetData
```

The business Logic Layer is responsible for data validation from the business point of view. In this example, we will apply a ten percent discount for the books published in 2005 and a twenty percent discount for books published in 2004. We need to create a file in the root folder named books.php as shown

```
<?php
class bo_books {
//public
public $title = array();
public $image = array();
public $author = array();
public $description = array();
public $year = array();
public $price = array();
public $discount = array();
public $discounted = array();
//private
protected $DataObject;
function __construct()
{
$this->DataObject = new books();
}
public function apply_discount()
{
$this->title = $this->DataObject->title;
$this->image = $this->DataObject->image;
$this->author = $this->DataObject->author;
$this->description = $this->DataObject->description;
$this->year = $this->DataObject->year;
$this->price = $this->DataObject->price;
$j = 0;
foreach($this->year as $year)
{
if ($this->year[$j] == '2004')
$this->discount[$j] = '20';
elseif ($this->year[$j] == '2005')
$this->discount[$j] = '10';
$this->discounted[$j] = intval($this->price[$j] * (100 - $this->discount[$j]) ) / 100 ;
$j++;
};
} // end function apply_discount()
} // end class bo_books
```

The Presentation Layer:  First, we need to pass the variables from the Business Logic Layer to the Presentation Layer. In the root folder, we create a file named index.php like this:

```
<?php

require("libs/Smarty.class.php");
require_once("get_data.php");
require_once("books.php");

$book = new bo_books();
$book->apply_discount();

$smarty = new Smarty; 

$smarty->assign("book",$book);

$smarty->display('index.tpl');

?>
```

Next, we create an `index.tpl` file in the `templates` folder

```
<html>
<head> <title> Site Architecture Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="left">
<a href="http://www.packtpub.com">
<img src="images\Packt.png" border="0">
</a>
<img src="images\focused.gif">
</td>
<td>
<h1> Chapter 2 Example </h1>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
Here are the books in a two-column table :
<br> <br>
<table border="1" width="100%">
{section name=tbl loop=$book->title}
{if %tbl.index% is not odd}
<tr>
{/if}
<td align="left">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="images\{$book->image[tbl]}" width="220">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<font size=+1><b> {$book->title[tbl]} </b></font><br>
<font size=-1 color=blue><b> {$book->author[tbl]} </b></font><br>
{$book->description[tbl]} <br>
Year: {$book->year[tbl]} <br>
<font size=-1>Cover Price: <s>${$book->price[tbl]}</s></font> <br>
Our Price: ${$book->discounted[tbl]}
<font color=red> save {$book->discount[tbl]} % </font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
{if %tbl.index% is odd}
</tr>
{/if}
{/section}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As I run the program

> **Notice:** Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\MyCode\get_data.php on line 28" is diplayed.

The line 28 on `get_data.php` is

```
list($what, $content) = explode("=>", $line);
```

Can anyone suggest something or even help ?

Comment: That means that `explode` is returning an array with only 1 element, so you can't assign it to two variables.

Comment: Hey Manish, This is a very thorough post which is good, but in this case, we really need a broken down example. It seems like the only thing that's relevant here is your get_data.php. Your bo, smarty template, and everything else has nothing to do with your problem. Can you break it down to a solid specific example. Paste the output of `var_dump($lines);` before your loop.

Comment: @Barmar, hmm. How do i add the other array?.

Comment: This would happen if `$line` doesn't have `=>` on it. Put `var_dump($line);` and see what it shows when the error happens.

Comment: Wow. You posted all that code to try to get help with a relatively self-explanatory error message? I would like to refer you to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php  I also think a little basic debugging as mentioned by @Barmar is all you need to investigate this problem further.

Comment: @Barmar, okay, let me try.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the blank lines between the titles aren't really empty, they have a bunch of spaces on them. Try trimming before testing `strlen()`.

Comment: @MikeBrant, I have been penalized before for not being specific. So had to lay the whole thing down. :P

Comment: @Barmar, ill do that too. A big thank you.

Comment: @Manish Fair enough. I think you went too far this time :)  You really only need parts of the code that are relevant to the the problem. I don;t think the display layer makes any difference here.  It is just whatever happenson `get_data.php` line 28 and upstream call stack, including your data source.

Comment: @MikeBrant, :), I'll keep your advice and try not to over do my question/queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barmar said, the problem is you have an array with less **or more** than two elements in some point of your file. See line 15 of `data.txt` and you will find a second `=>`, so I guess that is the problem.

Try to fix the line 28 of `get_data.php` to this:

```
list($what, $content) = array_pad(explode('=>', $line, 2), 2, null);
```

So you will ALWAYS have two elements in your array.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6686831/2905135).

Answer (score 0):

The value of $line is 1.

```
$str = 1;
list($what, $content) = explode("=>", $str);
```

Gives this notice:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in test.php on line 7