# Getting error: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, explode

Its look like everything ok. It shows the result as well but it also shows **Undefined offset: 1** error. Please help me with this.

[image]

```
$url = "http://www.test.com";
$pageContent = file_get_contents($url);
$stepA = explode("</title>",$pageContent);
$stepB = explode("<title>",$stepA[0]);
$stepC = $stepB[1];
if($stepC == "Not Found"){
    echo $stepC = "NA";
} else{
    echo $stepC = "ok";
}
```

Comment: Check `isset` before you access array index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined offset when using php explode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807849/undefined-offset-when-using-php-explode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 with array when reading data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456325/php-notice-undefined-offset-1-with-array-when-reading-data)

Comment: But it works ok. If title is not set in a web page, undefined offset can throw

Answer (score 1):

Add some code like bellow:

```
$url = "http://www.test.com";
$pageContent = file_get_contents($url);

$stepA = explode("</title>",$pageContent);

if(isset($stepA)) {
    $stepB = explode("<title>",$stepA[0]);

    $stepC = isset($stepB) ? $stepB[1] : null;

    if($stepC == "Not Found"){
        echo $stepC = "NA";
    } else{
        echo $stepC = "ok";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use preg_match_all with regex simply you code 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php

```
$url = "http://www.test.com";
$pageContent = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match_all("#<title>(.*)<\/title>#sU",$pageContent, $matches);


 if(isset($matches[0][1]) && $matches[0][1] == "Not Found")
        $stepC = "NA";
 } else{
        $stepC = "ok";
 }
 echo $stepC;
```