# Explode return Undefined offset: 0 and probably breaks ajax responce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am adding input field with JQuery, when given condition is fulfilled.That input field should serve as a live search, so i attached on it on keyup event which must send through ajax the value of field in php side page, which page should check in database results which matching the given word or letter, and return the results in form of json object.

But problem is there that my explode is giving PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in ...  And from there my Ajax returns No conversion from text to object. And nothing is printed as result in the DOM or console,but in network tab i get what i want ... Its really confusing there is all step by step:

```js
$('#intake_goal_main').after('<input type = "text" name = "intake-search-field " class = "intake-search-field"/>');
    
    
    $('.intake-search-field').on('keyup',function(){
        var intake_search_product_name = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:     "POST",
        data: {'product_name':intake_search_product_name},
        cache:    false,
        url:      '/ajax/intake/intake_search.php',
        dataType: JSON,
        success:        function(result){
            
            $('.intake-food-result').remove();
            
           // $('.intake-search-field').after('<div class = "intake-food-result"></div>').html(result);
            
           
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
    })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="intake_goal_main"><select id="intake-pick-goal"><option>-- Изберете цел --</option><option value="intake-bulk">Покачване на килограми</option><option value="intake-cut">Сваляне на килограми</option><option value="intake-maintenance">Поддържане на килограми</option></select> </section>
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['product_name'])) {


  $product_name  =$_POST['product_name'];
  $req = ("SELECT * FROM food_data_bg WHERE ");
  $term = explode(" ",$product_name); //here is the problem...!!!!
  $i=0;

foreach($term as $form){
     $i++;
    if($i == 1){
    
       $req .= "title LIKE '%".$form."%'";
       
    }else{
    
       $req .= "OR title LIKE '%".$form."%'";
    }
    
}


require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/connection.php';
  $req = mysqli_query($connect,$req);
  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($req);

  if($num_rows == 0){
  
    $no_result = 'Няма резултати';
    echo json_encode($no_result);
    exit();
    
  }

else{
   $result = array();
   
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req)){
    $title= $row["title"];
    $myID= $row["id"];
    $image = $row["fimage"];
    $state = $row["state"];

      $result[] = array(
          'title' => $title,
          'id'    => $myID,
          'image' => $image,
          'state' => $state

          );
       }
       echo json_encode($result);
       exit();
    }
}

?>
```

There is also my network tab:

- [Preview network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Em7.png)
- [Response network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEEaX.png)

I am really sorry for long question, i am pretty confused why isn't my ajax working.So in short:

-Why does Explode returns Undefined Index : 0 in... ? If you need any more information, ask ! Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807849/undefined-offset-when-using-php-explode

Comment: Already tried it,it doesn't work...

Comment: what does print_r($term) produce for you

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => я
)
Here (in result from print_r($term))every character is populated after on keyup

Comment: If the print_r($term) gave you the Array ( [0] => я ), then it should go through the following loop at least once.  I would echo out something in your loop to see whats going on there.