# PHP explode only working when I suppress error

Tags: php

I am using the explode function in php to split a string like "60-5000"
into two elements that can be cast to integers.

```
$parts = explode('-', '60-5000',2);

$this->p1 = (integer)$parts[0];
$this->p2 = (integer)@$parts[1];
```

When this is ran in the constructor of my class I am getting this error:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

When I suppress the error on the second element of the array I obtain the correct array

```
0 => "60"
1 => "5000"
```

Above is the debug statement with error suppressed on the second index.

I do not want to keep having to suppress this error to get the results from explode. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined offset when using php explode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807849/undefined-offset-when-using-php-explode)

Comment: Show more code.

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) **does not** generate the `Undefined offset` notice. The code that uses `$parts` tries to access the value at a non-existent index and produces the notice when the string you split using `explode()` does not contain any `'-'`. `$parts` contains only one item in this case, at index `0`, `$parts[1]` does not exist and trying to access it for reading produces the notice. Check it out: https://3v4l.org/LTr03

Comment: @axiac I beg to differ since when I suppress the error both array elements are given and there is always a '-' between two numbers

Comment: working fine here : see https://eval.in/1017612

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox where the issue is reproducible? I copied your code (changed only the names of the variables, it doesn't affect the behaviour) and it still works fine: https://3v4l.org/GE8Ac, https://3v4l.org/nCRjI

Comment: Closevote because not reproducible. @axiac has given the most fitting explanation, other possible causes might be: The notice comes from a completely different line/file, or, the symbol `-` is written in different variations, like `—`, `-`, `‐`, `‑` (those are all different symbols). You should write a test case for this. Keep one thing in mind: If the index does not exist, it does not exist. PHP does not lie to you.

Comment: With suppression of errors I get what is expected with out I get the error. PHP is lying